# Join tables in QGis 2.01. Dufour

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-2, attribute-joins

I performed a "join" going to the properties option in a shapefile (in this case is just a table), in order to join the attributes from another shapefile that has a field in common, specifically "OBJECT_ID".

Some features appear with the right numbers and others with "Null".

However, in the shapefile I wish to join the information is correct and there is no "Null" in the trable.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Rita! Perhaps there's an "OBJECT_ID" value that only appears in one shapefile?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not think that happened, because I've performed this join before and it matched. However, I needed to recalculate an area in the table I want to join and now that happens to some of the values.